Converting WebRTC to RTMP
I am planning to build a live video conferencing application using the Google Cloud Live Streaming API on my own. I receive user input from WebRTC. However, Google Live Streaming only accepts input in RTMP format. I want to convert the WebRTC stream to RTMP format using FFmpeg, but I'm stuck at this stage.
Also, Please let me know if there are any other way for converting WebRTC to RTMP?

Gstreamer can do this for you.

Check out rtp-forwarder I have a RTMP example at the bottom.
This can be done with other languages/tools if you have a preference
